# Prove if $\forall a\neq 0, f(x)=af(ax)$, then $\exists k, f(x)=\frac{k}{x}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Somehow I can't figure out how to prove this seemingly obvious result (assuming we're only dealing with $\mathbb{R}$):

if $\forall a\neq 0, f(x)=af(ax)$, then $\exists k, f(x)=\frac{k}{x}$

Comment: Since the identity is true for all $a, x \neq 0$, simply relate $a$ and $x$ so that $ax = 1$. Then $f(x) = \frac{f(1)}{x}$.

Comment: Let $f (1)=k$ for sx\ne 0$, $f (x)=x*f (1)=x*k $ so doesn't appear to be true.